# "Conflicting distribution: InRelease (expected release but got release+1)" what it is?

Tags: apt

While updating my apt lists, I saw the following warning;

```
W: Conflicting distribution: http://security.debian.org testing/updates InRelease (expected stretch but got buster)
```

What it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=841874) it's a warning when the Suite/Codename (testing/toy story character) doesn't match with what you have on your sources.list file. In this case, the suite changed as you are using testing. It expected that the codename name stretch wouldn't change for the testing suite, but since the release freeze is over, the warning appeared.

This warning appeared again after 1.4~beta1 and you should expect it if you are using suites in your sources.list instead of codenames.